# Update column in different table, Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi im doing a paypal payment, anyway, when i update the just the date and active to 1, i have no problems..

But there is a active column , in a player table (not users table) that need to be updated to 1 because its 0 by default.

How can this be done.. because i get 'undefined local variable or method `player' for #'

here is my code

```
class PaymentNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :player_id, :transaction_id, :params, :status, :active

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :player
  serialize  :params
  after_create :mark_susc_as_purchased

  private

  def mark_susc_as_purchased
    if status == "Completed"
      user.update_attributes(:purchased_at => Time.now)
      user.update_attributes(:active => 1)
      player.update_attributes(:active => 1)

    end
  end
end
```

My first guess is :active must me something else like player.active.. but that dosent work eitheir.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now

```
def mark_susc_as_purchased
    if status == "Completed"
      user.update_attributes(:purchased_at => Time.now)
      user.update_attributes(:active => 1)
      user.player.update_attributes(:active => 1)
    end
  end
```